# Destructuring with default objects for nested object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, destructuring

I have a requirement where I have to take a couple of values from a nested object which when not available, should be taken from a default object. For example consider the following object:

```
const objToDestructure={
   someVal:3,
   anotherVal:4,
   outerObj:{}
}
```

If I want to take two field `field1` and `field2` from `outerObj` then what I was able to do was

```
const { someVal,anotherVal,outerObj = {field1:22,field2:33}}=objToDestructure;
const {field1,field2}=outerObj;
```

Is there anyway this can be shortened even more? I tried to do the following:

```
const { someVal,anotherVal,outerObj:{field1,field2} = {field1:22,field2:33}}=objToDestructure;
```

But I got both the values as `undefined`. Is there any reason why this won't work but the individual assignment does?

Comment: just as a suggestion, shorter does not imply more readable. Sometimes destructuring nested objects can be a bit trickier to read for the rest of the devs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `outerObj` exists (it's not `undefined`) in `objToDestructure`, setting a default for it won't help in this case. Since it's an object, you can destructure `field1` and `field2` individually, and set a default for each of them:

Set a default empty object, and add a default value for each field:

```
const { outerObj:{ field1 = 22, field2 = 33} = {}} = objToDestructure;
```

Example:

```js
const objToDestructure={
   someVal:3,
   anotherVal:4,
   outerObj:{}
}

const { outerObj: { field1 = 22, field2 = 33} = {}} = objToDestructure

console.log(field1, field2)
```

Comment: I know that for separate values it can be done. is there anyway that this can done in a shortened way where we give the defaults as an object instead of specifying separately each field?

Comment: option 2 is not visible

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: in my attempt to make the question smaller i left out some details. terribly sorry. can you take a look now please